# How to reset game when user loses

Tags: javascript

I'm one month into my school program, so I'm very new at this. I'm making a game where the computer gets a random letter and the user has 10 guesses to answer correctly. After the user gets to 0 guesses left, a confirm() message appears. I want to reset the guesses left to 10 and erase the letters guessed, while keeping the wins and losses tallied.  Is there a way to do this without refreshing the page?

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
"l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", 
"z"];
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guessesLeft = 10;
var guessesLetter = "";
var letter = []

var winsText = document.getElementById("wins-text");
var lossesText = document.getElementById("losses-text");
var guessesLeftText = document.getElementById("guesses-left-text");
var guessesLetterText = document.getElementById("guesses-letter-text");

 document.onkeyup = function(event) {

  var userGuess = event.key;
    letter.push(userGuess)
  var computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

    if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
        wins++;
    }else {
        guessesLeft--;
    }
    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
        losses++;
        confirm("GAME OVER, SUCKA! Try again?")
    }
```

Comment: Make a method that does the resets you want, then call the method after the call to `confirm`

Answer (score 0):

Make a method with a logical name (reset_game() for example).  within this method we can clear the array *letter* by saying `letter = []` and reset the guesses left by saying `guessesLeft = 10`.  Like ps2goat said this should be done after the confirmation to try again.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work. Thanks for your message, though...I appreciate it!

Comment: var computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        
        if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
            wins++;
        }else {
            guessesLeft--;
        }
        if (guessesLeft === 0) {
            losses++;
            confirm("GAME OVER, SUCKA! Try again?")
        }
        function newGame () {
            guessesLeft = 10;
            letter = [];
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
function game() {
    var letters = [
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
        "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y",
        "z"
    ];
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    var guessesLeft = 10;
    var guessesLetter = "";
    var letter = [];

    var winsText = document.getElementById("wins-text");
    var lossesText = document.getElementById("losses-text");
    var guessesLeftText = document.getElementById("guesses-left-text");
    var guessesLetterText = document.getElementById("guesses-letter-text");

    document.onkeyup = function(event) {

        var userGuess = event.key;
        letter.push(userGuess);
        var computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

        if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
            wins++;
        } else {
            guessesLeft--;
        }
        if (guessesLeft === 0) {
            losses++;
            confirm("GAME OVER, SUCKA! Try again?");
        }
    };

    function start()
    {
        // Set all elements to default values here
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of your game as needed.

```
var game1 = new game();
game1.start();

// on start game button
game1 = new game();
```

Just don't forget to reset your values in any user interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
function guess(letter) {
    if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
        endGame(true)
    }else {
        guessesLeft--;
    }
    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
        endGame(false)
    }
}

function endGame(winner) {
    guessesLeft = 10;
    guessesLetter = "";
    letter = []
    if (winner) {
        wins++
        confirm("Congrats! Try again?")
    } else {
        losses++
        confirm("GAME OVER, SUCKA! Try again?")
    }
}
```